# Hire experts to help out small Stackexchange sites with lots of unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Stackexchange currently has two travel-related websites:

- Travel.SE - ~30th most popular Site on the Network
- Expats.SE - ~60th most popular Site

The strength of Travel.SE is in having experts in given topics - US visas, UK visas, Schengen visas, experts on rail transport, etc. Visa matters are generally easy to answer and millions of people deal with them every year. Likewise lots of people can answer a general question like 'How to sleep on a train?'.

However Expats.SE is struggling with being useful as it deals with complex immigration matters and only immigration law experts can answer many of those. [One fifth](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) of their questions are Unanswered and existing Answers often lack in quality, which makes it hard to attract new visitors.

Could Stackexchange consider **hiring** some experts to provide answers on struggling sites, in order to help them set-up core user bases? It won't guarantee that a site manages to 'graduate', but it might be worth a try.

Comment: In addition to the reasons given in the link and in Shadow's answer; expats went through [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732?phase=beta) just like any other site. Not all sites survive. Expats is no exception. If the community isn't self-sustainable then the community cannot survive, so the community must find ways to draw expertise in on its own, and if the site fizzles out, then such is the way of things, and a new proposal can be made for a new site, incorporating lessons learned. You're essentially proposing the equivalent of a government bailout for SE sites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While this is an interesting idea, I think this is against the spirit of Stack Exchange.

True, there are small sites who can really use more experts.

True, hiring experts would help those sites, in the short run.

However, core feature of Stack Exchange is that it is 100% free, and no money is involved in neither asking, nor answering.

If we introduce such a thing as "paid expert" it's opening a Pandora's Box, as it mix money with answering. People will get that quickly, and offer money to get better answers. People with more money will get more answers. And this is totally against what Stack Exchange is.

Such experts are expected to join, for free, out of their own free will, during the Area 51 proposal life cycle. If no experts join, better not launch the site to begin with, but that's the decision of Stack Exchange team, case by case of course.

Comment: +1 and this is only like, the tip of the tip of the tip of the iceberg on a planet that consists of nothing but icebergs in a star system that consists of a dozen planets that are full of icebergs, and then some. There are so many reasons on so many levels not to do this. Also it's vaguely reminiscent of Experts Exchange's model.

Comment: Paying somebody to answer a question would require you to pay to view that answer.  There already are websites where that model was attempted

Comment: @Ramhound not always, I have another idea in mind, might post another answer. It's related to CMs.